# Adding JQuery Plugin to New MVC4 Web Application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to MVC 4 and JQuery.  This is a simple question, but I'm providing extra information in case it helps.  My question is **"How do I incorporate a simple jquery plugin into the MVC 4 framework?"**  I've been completely unsuccessful incorporating jquery plugins into my project.  I have gotten the "alert" document.ready test to work, but I haven't gotten any plugin to work when incorporating it into the MVC framework.  I've searched all over for a solid tutorial on this but can't find anything.

I would appreciate an answer to the general question above, or an answer to what I'm doing wrong with the following implementation.  I'm trying to add a picture carousel to the layout of a new MVC web application project.  I must have something out of place, because the slides jquery plugin works perfectly apart from MVC 4 (see html at bottom), but the images just show up next to each other on the page after adding everything to the new MVC 4 project.  Before placing into my MVC project, I paired down the slides so that no css is needed, and verified it works outside of MVC 4.  Please help!--been stuck on this long time.  Here is my code:

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p class="site-title">@Html.ActionLink("your logo here", "Index", "Home")</p>
            </div>
            <div class="float-right">
                <section id="login">
                    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                </section>
                <nav>
                    <ul id="menu">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="body">
        @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
        <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
            @RenderBody()
        </section>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET MVC Application</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <div id="slides">
        <img src="~/Images/Home_AEB3075%20(1).jpg" width="464" height="309" />
        <img src="~/Images/Home_AEB3075%20(2).jpg" width="464" height="309" />
        <img src="~/Images/Home_AEB3075%20(3).jpg" width="464" height="309" />
    </div>


    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#slides').slidesjs({
                width: 464,
                height: 309,
                play: {
                    active: true,
                    auto: true,
                    interval: 4000,
                    swap: true
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

**BundleConfig.cs**

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.ui.slides.js"));
```

Comment: How did you know to put it in the bundles in the first place?

Comment: You don't have to.  It just makes things cleaner than putting each script in _Layout.cshtml separately.  You can bundle all jquery related to one theme.  Then if you want to completely change themes/layouts, you can just grab a different bundle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh, the problem was that the script in my BundleConfig.cs file was not named correctly.  The script is jquery.slides.js, not jquery.slides.ui.js.  It all worked perfectly after putting in the correct script name.